# Getting data from Resource Guru

Tags: html, excel, vba, api

I trying to fetch data from a web page (Resource Guru), which is main of our planing of engineers around the world to excel. 
While I'm new to the "getting data from web" I tried some stuff I found on google like :

```
Dim request As Object
  Dim response As String
  Dim html As New HTMLDocument
  Dim website As String
  Dim price As Variant


'Define URL
website = "https://app.resourceguruapp.com/somestuff/companyname/resources"

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

request.Open "GET", website, False

request.setRequestHeader "IF-Modified-since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
MsgBox (response)
html.body.innerHTML = response

price = html.getElementsByClassName("_2tZlDeCUZ8Ga_4930sUxi7")(0).innerText

MsgBox (price)
```

For easy web pages, those containing fuel prices, the code works well. On the web page I want the data from it returns nothing into the variable "price". The response is somehow cryptic, I wanted to share a picture but I cant while I'm new to the forum.

My question is: 
Am I having a problem with the login to that page? 
Am I having trouble with the response in a wrong format? 
Am I having a problem with the programming languages?

Thanks for a reply!

Comment: You can upload an image to a sharing site and include the link in your post.  There's really no way for us to know what the problem is without seeing the actual page or at least the relevant HTML.  It's possible the content you want is dynamic (ie. loaded via script after the initial page loads in the browser) in which case this approach will not work: you'd need to do something like automate IE to get that content.

Comment: Also check to see if the element is in an iFrame. If so, try finding the element from inside the iFrame.

Comment: Already thanks for the supply ! Good Point, see picture of the output of the variable response here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/crs23kw8v6a7thh/Reply.jpg?dl=0

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in the console of the browser - so the elements I'm trying to fetch: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xuonc44n9hd7332/Console.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm an engineer at Resource Guru. It looks like you are trying to scrape the contents of the generated html page on the resources page. We actually have an API which you can use to get access all the data you need. You can find the API documentation here: https://github.com/resourceguru/api-docs

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply, yes found this already and can use this through Excel power query editor. Having problems with this now but at least the data is in the program. Thanks to all and post solved